# Impossible to upload data on firestore React Native Expo

Tags: firebase, react-native, google-cloud-firestore

I was trying to upload user data on firestore after the login, so I created a function in my file Fire.js

```
    createUser = async user => {


    try {
        await firebase.auth().createUserWithEmailAndPassword(user.email, user.password);

        let db = this.firestore.collection("users").doc(this.uid);

        db.set({
            name: user.name,
            email: user.email,
            followed:{},
            follower:{},
            avatar: null
        });


    } catch (error) {
        console.log(user)
        alert("Error: ", error);
    }
};
```

and after I called this function on my RegisterScreen. js

```
handleSignUp = () => {
    Fire.shared.createUser(this.state.user);
};
```

someone could tell me why is impossible for me to upload these data on firestore?

Comment: What's the error you get?

Comment: thank you for your interest!  The terminal doesn't show nothing, just an allert on the iphone

Comment: Please tell the alert you get, without more info on the errors it's very hard to know what problem you have

Comment: Hi simon, the error is this: Can't find variable crypto